# IntelliJ IDEA: how to quickly navigate to a particular package

Tags: intellij-idea

A project has too many packages and packages are very deep. How to quickly navigate to a particular package?

For example, a package `com.nmj.edu.pox.els.excel.service` in the project, how to quickly navigate to it? Is there a way like `Navigate to a file`?

[image]

How to quickly locate `org.junit.internal.builders` package according to the full package path when `junit.extensions.ActiveTestSuite` is selected or the directory tree is folded?
I

[image]

My question is **not** about locating that package according to the opened file.

Comment: In Navigate | File action you can filter by directory (corresponding to a package) name with the `/` separation. With this action you navigate to a class in target package. then use Main menu | Navigate | Jump to Navigation Bar action (Alt+Home default Windows shortcut)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Navigate | File** action you can filter by directory (corresponding to a package) name with the `/` separator. With this action you can navigate to the package in the project tool window or open the class from this package in Editor.

Then, depending on what you need

- use Main menu | Navigate | [**Jump to Navigation Bar**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-with-navigation-bar.html) action (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> default Windows shortcut) to select any other class in that package or browse package structure
- or use Main menu | Navigate | Select In... (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) -> Project View action to navigate to this class in Project tool window.

Also with the **Packages** view and the **Flatten Packages** [option enabled in Project tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-scopes.html#d701968e254) you could be able to find the package using [speed search](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/speed-search-in-the-tool-windows.html) (provided that the corresponding package node is visible in the view).

Relate request in tracker: [IDEA-35362](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-35362)

Answer (score 2):

Once you have opened the file, click on Scroll from Source.
It will open the whole package hierarchy for the selected file.
PFB screenshot for reference to locate the Scroll from Source button.
[image]

**Note:** There is no keymap for this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is actually. Have you checked the [Intellij IDEA Navigation Docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-through-the-source-code.html)?

Comment: I want to locate that particular package in the `Project View`.

Comment: You could use 'Scroll from Source' button below the navigation bar, but there's no keymap for it afaik.

Comment: The source file hasn't displayed in the right editor. My question is not about locating that package according to the opened file.

Comment: after you navigate to the file/package, you use 'Scroll from Source', that's how you view the file and its location in project view